# C++ just a syntax error: syntax error : identifier

Tags: c++, syntax, identifier

I feel so dumb right now:

```
moveSequence look(COORD xyBeatle, fieldd &field);
```

what could be so wrong about that, to give a syntax error?

```
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'fieldd'
```

What I am trying to do is pass an a reference of a class `fieldd` to `look()` via:

```
moveSequence sequence = look(xy, m_field);
```

It doesn't seem to recognize the type field

Actually I am being littered with errors  all about things that should be type field are having type int assumed ect..

This is after a long week of refactoring and not even getting back to the point of compiling so I cannot tell what change immediately caused this.

---

edit: now I am noticing that intellisense is underlining, for only a moment, intermittently the places where the compiler is throwing real errors..... I disabled PCH and rebuilt but this didn't work.

---

edit2:
The variable name was NOT the problem, that was one of the first things I Tried.

---

edit3:
I was finally able to catch one of the intellisense errors and it read `"identifier "fieldd" is undefined"` before shortly changing to `"class fieldd"` I think this might be a problem with the headers. this guys problem was headers: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/555445-solvederror-c2061-syntax-error--identifier-t3dobject/

Comment: A *week* of refactoring? Back before there was a name for that, we just called it a "rewrite"!

Comment: it pretty much was, it got out of hand. Every time I read SO I learn how to do something "more right" and it looked good for a minute, until  I realized that it had broken something else....which let to more searching on SO.... loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We really need more code to identify your problem but I wonder if you need to forward declare fieldd since you have refactored the code into different files, perhaps the headers are not included correctly or the dependencies no longer make sense?

changing your declaration to: moveSequence look(COORD xyBeatle, class fieldd &field)
might give you more information.

Comment: it was circular header includes, and the forward declarations fixed it!...only to expose hundreds of other errors in the next file i have to fight through..including linking issues, thanks for getting me unstuck.

Answer (score 3):

`field` appears to be a type name.  Use a different variable name.

Comment: before  I do that, I will say that the class named `field` wasn't a problem before I changed things. Could this still be the issue?

Comment: I can't answer that as I don't know what you changed.  But going from the code above, as that's all you've given us to go on, it appears to be doing the equivalent of using `int int` as an argument to a function or method.  See why that wouldn't work?

Comment: I agree with your prescription of making the argument name different from the argument type.  But it isn't analogous to `int int`, because `int` is a keyword.

Comment: well I changed every reference of the type name.. `syntax error : identifier 'fieldd'` still the same

Comment: Just to reiterate, changing the class name had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

`fieldd` is not recognized as a type if I understand well.

Does  `fieldd foobar` works over the line triggering the error? If not it's likely that you're missing the include declaring `fieldd`.